# I want to perform the animation on the custom view cell in ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel, uibezierpath

I have an requirement like on taping on tableView cell it should animate and dropped (jumped)to trash icon.

Am using `UIBezierPath` to animate the text and jump function but I cant move the label which is inside the tableViewCell.

Any idea and suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Here check the below code so far I have done.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSMutableArray  *views=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    int i=0;
    int j=indexPath.row;
    UIView *anim = nil;
    UIView *vi2;
    for (UIView *theview in destination.superview.subviews) 
    {
//                if (theview.tag != 2)
//                    continue;
        NSLog(@"%@",theview);
        if ([theview isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]]) 
        {
           // NSLog(@"%@",theview);
            UIView *vi= theview;//(UITableView *)[UITableView class];
           // NSLog(@"%@",vi);

           // NSMutableArray  *views=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            for(UIView *vi1 in vi.subviews )
            {
                NSLog(@" the current view....%@",vi1);
                for (int k = 0; k < [arrayList count]; k++)
                {
                    [views insertObject:vi1 atIndex:i++];
                    NSLog(@" ddddd %@",[views objectAtIndex:i-1]);

                }
               }
              //  vi1=(UITableViewCell*)[tableElements objectAtIndex:i];
                anim=(UIView *)[views objectAtIndex:j];
                anim = vi2;   

            for (int k = 0; k < [views count]; k++)
                NSLog (@"Element %d = %@", k, [views objectAtIndex: k]); 



            break;
          }
        }

    if (!anim)
        return;

    UIBezierPath *movePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [movePath moveToPoint:anim.center];
    [movePath addQuadCurveToPoint:destination.center
                     controlPoint:CGPointMake(destination.center.x, anim.center.y)];

    CAKeyframeAnimation *moveAnim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    moveAnim.path = movePath.CGPath;
    moveAnim.removedOnCompletion = YES;

    CABasicAnimation *scaleAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
    scaleAnim.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DIdentity];
    scaleAnim.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeScale(0.1, 0.1, 1.0)];
    scaleAnim.removedOnCompletion = YES;

    CABasicAnimation *opacityAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"alpha"];
    opacityAnim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
    opacityAnim.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.1];
    opacityAnim.removedOnCompletion = YES;

    CAAnimationGroup *animGroup = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
    animGroup.animations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:moveAnim, scaleAnim, opacityAnim, nil];
    animGroup.duration = 0.5;
    [anim.layer addAnimation:animGroup forKey:nil];
}
```

Arun..

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Best site on the net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest to make snapshot of your cell and put it on the current main view in hierarchy (mostly it will self.view) as UIImageView. You delete you cell from table as is, but apply animation for that UIImageView. I've done this trick when tried to make drag-n-drop with UITableViews.